# WinUI3: How to change the size of a rectangle at runtime

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, winui-3, winui

## The Goal

I want to build an audio visualizer based on [1/3 octaves](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/octave-bands-frequency-limits-d_1602.html) like this one in an WinUI3 app:
[image]

I already have the sampling part, I only need to deal with the rendering and visual part.

## What Have I tried?

While looking at the [WinUI3 Gallery App](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/winui-3-gallery/9P3JFPWWDZRC?hl=en-us&gl=US), I've found that you can modify rectangles in a nice way using either a translation or a scale modifier(and it's also animated):

```xml
<!-- Automatically animate changes to Scale -->
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Width="50" Height="50" Scale="1,1,1" >
    <Rectangle.ScaleTransition>
        <Vector3Transition />
    </Rectangle.ScaleTransition>
    <Rectangle.TranslationTransition>
        <Vector3Transition />
    </Rectangle.TranslationTransition>
</Rectangle>
```

```cs
using System.Numerics;
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rectangle.Scale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
    rectangle.Translation = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
}
```

Firstly I tried to have 11 very long rectangles and move them upwards using the value. The problem with this approach is that the rectangles cannot be bigger than the container. You can have a default scale that actually overrides this rule but it lead to blurry corners.

So I've decided to try to scale the Y value of the rectangles by the respective value for each octave.

## What I have

Right now I have 11 rectangles in a *StackPanel* named "rectangles", each rectangle looking like this

```xml
<Rectangle
    Width="50"
    Height="40"
    Margin="7,10,7,0"
    Fill="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}"
    RadiusX="7"
    RadiusY="3"
    Scale="1,0,1">

    <Rectangle.ScaleTransition>
        <Vector3Transition />
    </Rectangle.ScaleTransition>
    <Rectangle.TranslationTransition>
        <Vector3Transition />
    </Rectangle.TranslationTransition>
</Rectangle>
```

And a timer that runs this code every *10ms*:

```cs
private void FetchOctaves(object state)
{
    DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(DispatcherQueuePriority.High,
        () =>
        {
            if (!Audio.IsPlaying()) return;
            var octaves = Audio.GetFrequencyData().ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < octaves.Count; i++)
            {
                // Map() normalizes a value from a source min and max to a target min and max
                var yScale = Map(octaves[i], -60f, 20f, 1f, 12f);
                rectangles.Children[i].Scale = new Vector3(1, yScale, 1);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

## The Problem(s)

As you can figure, my solution is quite hardcoded and it leads to some problems:

#### 1. I cannot find a maximum scale value in order to appeal to all window sizes.

Bigger scale values make my rectangles go out of the container's bounds.
One solution to this would be to have a property *MaxScale* that adapts whenever the size of the container changes(I already modify the rectangle's *width* whenever this happens). But this doesn't solve the next issue:

#### 2. When met with big Y-scale values my rectangle's rounded corners start to look blurry.

This probably happens because of how the app handles scale(by zooming in).

## What I want

I want to know if there's a way to resize the actual height of the rectangles at runtime.
This would solve both of my problems and would allow me to make it responsive to different window sizes.

If that is not possible, I would appreciate if you would point me towards another solution to achieve this goal using WinUI3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: didn't understand what you want to do. Maybe try to change the `Rectangle` directly in code to set the height?